# yum: install local RPMs and all local dependencies

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf, rpm-spec

I have my locally generated `rpm` packages (the main package and its dependencies) located in my home directory. The `spec` file defined dependencies. I'd like to install it with a single `yum` or `dnf` command and let it find dependencies in my directory and install them accordingly. I tried `yum`:

```
% yum -y localinstall ~/rpms/mypackage-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

However it complains:

```
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides mypackage-libs(x86-64) = 2.1.1-2.1 needed by mypackage-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or this indicates that I have a bug in my `spec` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localinstall` won't pick the other RPMs from the folder automatically, it will try to install only the packages specified in the command (and it also installs dependencies but only from system repositories) so you either need to list all packages or use shell expansion:

```
yum -y localinstall ~/rpms/mypackage-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm ~/rpms/mypackage-libs-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

```
yum -y localinstall ~/rpms/*.rpm
```

(with `dnf` just use `dnf install` and the path(s) instead of `localinstall`).